# Python3 error “no module named bluetooth” on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, python, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Lenovo S10E to a Nintendo Wiimote via bluetooth. I am using a simple Python script, reproduced below. I am calling it from the Linux Mint (version 16, "Petra") command line using `python3 find_wii.py`

My goal is to connect a wiimote to Mint, then output MIDI (eventually). I am using Python due to its cross-platform advantages.

Script:

```
import bluetooth

target_name = "Nintendo RVL-CNT-01"
target_address = "00:1C:BE:29:75:7F"

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print("found target bluetooth device with address "), target_address
else:
    print("could not find target bluetooth device nearby")
```

I am receiving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_wii.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bluetooth
ImportError: No module named 'bluetooth'
```

I have installed bluez and python wrappings for it (`sudo aptitude install python-bluez`). I have upgraded my system (`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`). I did consulted Google, and the only official bugs I could find are [here](https://code.google.com/p/remuco/issues/detail?id=137) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/issues/detail?id=36), and neither of the answers worked for me.

How can I get the Bluetooth module to work with Mint?

[Note: Question [cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985163/python3-error-no-module-named-bluetooth-on-linux-mint) to stackoverflow]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252679/installing-bluez-in-python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the bluetooth module is for python2 and not yet for python3. You can verify this by trying to load the module with python2.